# Python mapping IDs to a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have "list_1" which is a list of 3000 dataframes. Also, I have "df_1" which is a single column dataframe containing 1000 IDs.

I want to iterate through all 3000 dataframes in "list_1", select from each dataframe the row corresponding to an ID from "df_1", and group the selected rows in a separate dataframe for each ID.

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Table.csv')

ids = table[['identification']]

#this folder contains 3000 csv files
folder_of_files= 'C:\\Users\\myself\\file{}.csv'

#create a list of 3000 dataframes
list_of_files = []
for i in range(0,3000):
   list_of_files.append(pd.read_csv(folder_of_files.format(i)))

mapped_id = []
alltogether = []

for x in ids:
   for y in range(0,3000):
      mapped_id.append(list_of_files[y].loc[list_of_files[y]['identification']==ids])
   alltogether.append(pd.concat(mapped_id))
```

I get the following error message: "ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key"

FYI: If I hardcode the "ids" as a value (i.e., 1234) it works.

Comment: Please add some code so that we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's really hard to answer questions like this -- it's too abstract. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See, `for x in ids: ... loc[list_of_files[y]['identification']==ids` lools like a typo to me. Sis not you plan to compare with `x` instead?